# Insert iframe and remove it by js

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code append a vimeo video. But when the vimeo video appears, I cant close it pressing `buttonClose`. When I press `buttonClose` It should delte the container `vimeoPop`. What's the issue?

```
<div class="vimeo-video">
         <div class="video">
            <a class="" href="#" yt-id="535941">
                <img>
            </a>
         </div>
</div>



var i = 1;
  var str1 = "n";
  $(".vimeo-video").each(function (index, value) {
    var maindiv = str1 + i;
    $(this).addClass(maindiv);
    $(".vimeo-video." + maindiv + " a").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var src = $(this).attr("yt-id");
      var link = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + src + "?autoplay=1";
      var iframe =
        '<div class="vimeoPop"><div class="buttonClose"><span></span><span></span></div><iframe frameborder="0" src="' +
        link +
        '" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
      $(".vimeo-video." + maindiv + " .video").append(iframe);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.buttonClose', function () {
      $(".vimeo-video" + maindiv + " .vimeoPop").remove();
    });
    i++;
  });
```

Comment: Because , your remove button are dynamically created just bind that element with static element i.e : `$(document).on('click','.buttonClose',function(){ // your code})`.

Comment: I edited with `$(document).on('click', '.buttonClose', function () {
      $(".vimeo-video" + maindiv + " .vimeoPop").remove();
    });` but doesnt work

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wqyrL9jo/) working code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing selector `.` for the class at remove line

instead of selecting  ".vimeo-video.n1" you are selecting ".vimeo-videon1"

```js
var i = 1;
  var str1 = "n";
  $(".vimeo-video").each(function (index, value) {
    var maindiv = str1 + i;
    $(this).addClass(maindiv);
    $(".vimeo-video." + maindiv + " a").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var src = $(this).attr("yt-id");
      var link = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + src + "?autoplay=1";
      var iframe =
        '<div class="vimeoPop"><div class="buttonClose"><span>Close</span><span></span></div><iframe frameborder="0" src="' +
        link +
        '" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
      $(".vimeo-video." + maindiv + " .video").append(iframe);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.buttonClose', function () {
      $(".vimeo-video." + maindiv + " .vimeoPop").remove();
    });
    i++;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vimeo-video">
         <div class="video">
            <a class="" href="#" yt-id="535941">
                <img>Click me
            </a>
         </div>
</div>
```